# JSON assign JObject property name with string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

The name of a property in my JSON object needs to be assigned via a string, how can I do this with a JObject? Or should I just JObject.parse from a string? I'm aware of the .Net Json documentation, however, it is very basic and does not show any examples like below.

Here is what I have now:

```
return JObject.FromObject(new { 
attachment = new { 
    type = "template",
    payload = new {
        template_type = "button",
        text = Title,
        buttons = new {
            type = type,
            Variable1 = Value,
            Variable2 = Payload
        }
    }               
}
});
```

Also, if I do it the string.parse way like below, is this the best way to format the string?

```
JObject.Parse(@"{
    attachment : { 
        type : 'template',
        payload : {
            template_type : 'button',
            text : '"+Title+@"',
                buttons : [{
                  type : '"+Type+@"',
                  "+Variable1+" : '"+Value+@"',
                  "+Variable2+" : '"+Payload+@"'
                }]      
        }
    }
}"
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the question.  In the first example, what is the string to be used as a property name?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string,object>`

Comment: @dbc So Variable1 and Variable2 can be assigned just fine in the second example because its a simple string. However, in the first example I can't assign the property names variable1 and variable2 with actual variables, when I run the code it takes the name Variable1 instead of its value.

Comment: @james: You two snippets are inconsistent. In the first, `buttons` is an object, in the second it's an array (with an object in it). Which is it?

Comment: The second is correct, sorry I didn't know how to do the first one correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually construct an inner `JObject` using the pattern from [Creating JSON: Creating JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm) contained inside an outer anonymous type object, then serialize the entire anonymous object to JSON:

```
var obj = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    attachment = new
    {
        type = "template",
        payload = new
        {
            template_type = "button",
            text = Title,
            buttons = new JArray( new JObject(
                new JProperty("type", Type),
                new JProperty(Variable1, Value),
                new JProperty(Variable2, Payload)))
        }
    }
});
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a1B1lJ).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Dictionary<string,object>` for `buttons`, for example:

```
var obj = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    attachment = new
    {
        type = "template", 
        payload = new
        {
            template_type = "button", 
            text = Title, 
            buttons = new object[] 
            { 
                new Dictionary<string,object>() 
                {
                    { "type", "type" },
                    { Variable1, Value },
                    { Variable2, Payload }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but any idea i this will perform better than JArray and JObjects like in the other answer?

Comment: @james: it's a lot less fiddly than having a whole bunch of `new JProperty` all over the place.

Comment: Btw your answer performs at an average of 28ms where as the other performs at an average of 10ms on my mac server. :)